# Can't install rmagick on debian 7.6 (package conflicts)

Tags: ruby, debian, redmine, rmagick

I'm trying to install redmine 2.5.4 on a Debian 7.6 (Wheezy). And i encounter a problem why I try to install rmagick gem.

I try `apt-get install libmagickwand-dev libmysqlclient-dev` and `apt-get install libmagick++-dev`but I can't install. Indeed, there a conflict has shown after :

```
maxime@ns504687:/opt/redmine$ sudo aptitude why-not libmagick++-dev
i   imagemagick                         Suggests  html2ps
p   html2ps                             Depends   perlmagick
p   graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat Provides  perlmagick
p   graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat Conflicts libmagick++-dev
```

Here is the result of `apt-get install libmagickwand-dev libmysqlclient-dev`

```
maxime@ns504687:/opt/redmine$ sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev libmysqlclient-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libmysqlclient-dev is already the newest version.
libmysqlclient-dev set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickwand-dev : Depends: libmagickcore-dev (= 8:6.7.7.10-5+deb7u3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And here the result for `apt-get install libmagick++-dev` :

```
maxime@ns504687:/opt/redmine$ sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagick++-dev : Depends: libmagickcore-dev (= 8:6.7.7.10-5+deb7u3) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libmagickwand-dev (= 8:6.7.7.10-5+deb7u3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried a lot of solutions find on the web but no one has worked.

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

So at least here is the tutorial from the Redmine Site
https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall

Just run the command

```
bundle install --without development test
```

and then

```
bundle install --without development test rmagick
```